# gSOAP 2.8.30 compatibility with VS6 C++

Tags: c++, c, windows, gsoap

I try to compile my window application with gSOAP 2.8.30 but i found an error which is

> wctomb_s undeclared identifier

So i just wandering if the latest gSOAP is not compatible with the VC6++ since this error come from stdsoap2.cpp. Before this i'm using gSOAP 2.8.6 is working fine.

Comment: this is related to encoding. try to compile with "character set" option set to "unset" : Properties/General/Character Set.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. but in VC6 does not have option to change the character set to unset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS6 C++ does not support `wctomb_s` (the recommended safer version of `wctomb`). Upgrade to a newer VS C++ release or update the code in `stdsoap2.cpp` function `soap_string_in` by replacing:

```
#ifdef WIN32
        m = 0;
        wctomb_s(&m, buf, sizeof(buf), (wchar_t)(c & 0x7FFFFFFF));
#else
        m = wctomb(buf, (wchar_t)(c & 0x7FFFFFFF));
#endif
```

with:

```
        m = wctomb(buf, (wchar_t)(c & 0x7FFFFFFF));
```

at both of the two locations where `wctomb_s` is used.